# Android Run time Permissions in Android 6.0 (API level 23) best practices

Tags: android, permissions

Android Run time Permissions in Android 6.0 (API level 23)  best practices

I have successfully added Permissions on the run time to my app using

These refrences

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

and

https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html

this is the code I have used

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    switch (id){
                case R.id.check_permission:
                    if (checkPermission()) {

                        Snackbar.make(view,"Permission already granted.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {

                        Snackbar.make(view,"Please request permission.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.request_permission:
                    if (!checkPermission()) {

                        requestPermission();

                    } else {

                        Snackbar.make(view,"Permission already granted.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    break;
            }

private boolean checkPermission(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }

    private void requestPermission(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){

            Toast.makeText(context,"GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Denied, You cannot access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

The best practices provided by android

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html

state  the following

1) Consider Using an Intent

2) Only Ask for Permissions You Need

3) Don't Overwhelm the User

4) Explain Why You Need Permissions

now following the above we ask permissions only when needed and only for the specific permission which is required by that activity

However **These best practices donot state the frequency of the permission , ie to say how many times these permission need to be shown or can it be shown only once**

now the problem that I am facing is

1) each time the activity is called in the app the permissions pop up, These happens for that particular session of app usage(if same activity is called during the same session the permission is not called for once it is granted)

2) Can we store permissions that have been granted (ie the static variable which performs the first check in shared preference so that permissions are not called again and again)

3) **Do we need to call for the permission access each time the app is used**

4) If shared preferences are not allowed how to we manage these permissions more elegantly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The documentation you referenced says:

> If your app needs a dangerous permission, you must check whether you
>   have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires
>   that permission. The user is always free to revoke the permission, so
>   even if the app used the camera yesterday, it can't assume it still
>   has that permission today.

That's why you have to request it every time.

2) You can't store permissions.  Android decides how long to remember a granted permissions.

3) Yes, that's what the above quote is saying.

4) You let Android manage the permissions. You don't do anything yourself except check or request them when you need them.