# How to apply successfully Runtime Permissions in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-permissions

I want to ask for any permission to the user after installing the app.

Is it possible to request runtime permissions from current API(7.0) to API level 19 (4.4)?

I've read the documentation and I've tried a lot of examples. 
Everything seems too complex and I've even seen plugins to request permissions.

The documentation provides an example usign several NuGet Packages:
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android-m/RuntimePermissions/

But it only works with Android M (6.0 API level 23) and above...

This article talks about it:
https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

For example, in my case I want to check if the app have the "permission CAMERA" and if not ask for the user, something like this:

```
if (Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != (int)Permission.Granted) {
    // Permission has never been accepted
    // So, I ask the user for permission
    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera }, REQUEST_CAMERA);
} else {
    // Permission has already been accepted previously
}
```

The application opens without displaying anything.
The check works but "RequestPermissions" don't ask anything to the user.

1. Why not show anything?
2. Why I need to use "ActivityCompat" if also doesn't work in versions prior to M?

**Can anyone give me an example to request runtime permission from a simple code (compatible with versions prior to M)?**

Comment: Since nobody has answered: can't give you a code example but at least some background. For device versions prior to M, users can't withdraw permissions. They are automatically granted at install time. So `ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission()` will always return true. Unfortunately, it will also return true if targetSDK < M and device is running M or higher, even if users revoked the permission. (this is true for native android dev, please test to make sure it's valid for xamarin as well. In native dev you can use `PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission()` in this case)

Comment: I would suggest you look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116612/android-6-0-1-permission-issue-wifimanager-getscanresults-returns-0/40116740?noredirect=1#comment67542054_40116740 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027167/android-run-time-permissions-in-android-6-0-api-level-23-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result as you, so did a little investigation. The trick is that you have to set permissions in 2 places.
1. In manifest
2. Request permissions in run time
As shown here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
the result is different.

**On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest**, as described in Declaring Permissions. However, the effect of that declaration is different depending on the system version and your app's target SDK level:

If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.
If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to **list the permissions in the manifest, and** it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Permissions were introduced in Android 6.0 (API 23 - Marshmallow).  As such you will not be able to programmatically set up Runtime Permissions on any Android API lower than 23.  The [Requesting Runtime Permissions in Android Marshmallow](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) guide you linked in your question is likely the best resource here, and the `Check the SDK Version` section shows the logic for checking the API level and preventing the Runtime Permissions workflows from being called on API levels prior to 23.

For previous API levels from 22 and prior you will need to add your install-time permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as described in the [Add Permissions to Android Manifest](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/permissions/) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting your `Permissions` in `Manifest.xml` you can check the permission using [Xamarin.Essentials: Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android)

It automatically prompt the user to Allow or Disallow the requested permissions.